# How to retain all current GET request parameters when changing the language by dropdown?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have a page that by clicking on a link it calls a method and does some work and passes the string as an output so the anther page can be displayed.

```
public String doTheMagic() {
    // I'm doing the magic here. Once my magic is done, return to the next page 
    // with return String so the other page can be displayed.
    return "../content/categoryview.jsf?cat="+e.getNewValue().toString()";
}
```

Everything fine so far.

I have on my header a drop down menu that changes language from English to let say French. My problem is when I change the language while staying on that page `../content/categoryview.jsf?cat=3` and change the language the page become `../content/categoryview.jsf`. It drops `?cat=3`. When the page is redisplayed and not having the `?cat=3` it throws the following exception.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
```

Is there a way to change my language and keep my URL intact?